# Prior Value in validation rule to find previous lookup field value

Tags: lightning-experience, lookup, validation-rule

There is a look up relation between 2 objects. Parent object has picklist field "State".The requirement is to create validation rule on child object to throw error if lookup field is changed and the previous parent the lookup was pointing to has state field as "NY".The validation rule i came up with is this

AND( ISPICKVAL(Parent_Object__r.State__c , "NY"),ISCHANGED( Lookup_Field__c ) )

but the error gets thrown if the lookup value is changed and new lookup value has state field as "NY".The requirement is to check if previous Parent the lookup was pointing to before changing lookup field and check if its State field was "NY". 
I am aware of PRIOR value function but not sure how to use it to get prior value of lookup.
How can that be achieved

Comment: Is `Lookup_Field__c` and `Parent_Object__c` and you forgot to replace it? if not, if the `Parent_Object__c` is changed at the same time as the `Lookup_Field__c`, which state you would like to check for `NY`, a) the one the record had before saving or b) the one that it has now?

Comment: @ Sergio Alcocer "Lookup_Field__c" is lookup to the parent object that means if lookup field changes parent object changes. The formula i have written checks in the new parent record  assigned before saving but  i want the value of parent record before the change was made and get its "state" field value in a formula field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have 2 objects, and the Lookup from the child to the parent is called `Lookup_Field__c`.

If that is the case, an easy way to achieve what you are looking for would be to

1. create a checkbox formula field in your child object `Parent_Object_Protected_State__c` that references the value you want to check (`ISPICKVAL(Lookup_Field__r.State__c,'NY')`)
2. Use the validation Rule `AND(ISCHANGED(Lookup_Field__c), PRIORVALUE(Parent_Object_Protected_State__c))`

You could as an alternative create a text formula field and check the state in the validation rule, but then you will have to play with `TEXT()` function